# Image renditions not working anymore

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page, image, front-end, image-rendition

On a SP 2013 on-prem publishing site, we are using Image Rendition. Suddenly Image renditions are not working anymore when trying to edit renditions from the ribbon on an article page. I can still edit renditions directly in the library.

I have tried `iisreset` and clearing the **blob cache**. I also checked if the `web.config` setting has been changed from `blobcahce=enabled`, which it had not.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Is [SharePoint Page Output Caching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261797.aspx) enabled? Please try to test on a fresh client machine that has never loaded the page or try to remove your local Temporary Internet Files. It's possible that you are refreshing a cached version of the page on your user machine.

Comment: Hi, it's enabled.Renditions are not working on the server where I am admin, but when I logged in as a another user from a machine outside of the server, then images ares shown with correct renditions. I tried flushing the cache, but the problem is still there on the server. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Image Renditions will work if you first flush the blob cache and then do IISRESET (otherwise it will still refer to the old blob).
Sometimes the blob cache will get corrupted and need to be created again.

`$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp2013.com"`

`[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)`

`iisreset`